# How to get function to return value synchronously when calling a Promise?

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise

I have a function that calls an async method which returns a promise. I need the function to return the value based on the promise's resolved value. But when I try to do this, typescript throws an error saying the value is being used before being defined.

```
const myFunction = async (id: string): MyProductInterface {

  let isvalidProduct = false;
  let myProduct: MyProductInterface;

  await myClient.clientmethod(id)
  .then((response) =>{
    if (response == "valid"){
      isvalidProduct = true; 
    }
  })

  if(isvalidProduct){
    myProduct = //code to create MyProductInterface object with some values set to true;
  }else{
    myProduct = //code to create MyProductInterface object with some values set to false;
  }

  return myProduct;
}
```

`clientmethod(id)` method is asynchronous but I need to wait for the promise to resolve because I return `myProduct` which is dependent of the resolution of the promise. How can I get this to work?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use `await` inside a function that isn't `async`.  The linter isn't complaining about that at all?

Comment: @David You are right. I was writing the code directly on stackoverflow. I missed `async`. Fixed it.

Comment: Why not only use async/await syntax: `const isvalidProduct = await myClient.clientmethod(id) === 'valid'`?

Comment: Are you sure you are sharing the part of your code that is raising the exception? In my opinion your code shouldn't raise the error you mentioned as you are using all your variables after they are defined. The only thing I see is the function declaration. It should be either `function myFunction async (id: string): Promise<MyProductInterface> {}` or `const myFunction = async (id: string): Promise<MyProductInterface> => {}`. Also note that the return type is a promise of your interface

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it more complicated than necessary:

```
async function myFunction(id: string): Promise<MyProductInterface> {

  const response = await myClient.clientmethod(id);
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  if (response == "valid") {
    return … //code to create object with some values set to true;
  } else {
    return … //code to create object with some values set to false;
  }
}
```

However, no, `myFunction(…)` is still asynchronous and will always return a promise, it is impossible to make it return synchronously. All the `await` does is to ensure that the `response` is checked and the result object is created after `myClient.clientmethod(id)` has finished.